# rpm can not decide if package is installed or not

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, java

Running `rpm -i jdk-6u45-linux-amd64.rpm` on `CentOS 7.0.1406` gives me:

```
package jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64 is already installed
```

However running `rpm -ql jdk-6u45-linux-amd64.rpm` gives:

```
package jdk-6u45-linux-amd64.rpm is not installed
```

Note: a newer version `Java` have been already installed on this machine.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is

```
rpm -ql jdk-6u45-linux-amd64
```

If that doesn't work, then what is actually installed is `jdk-2000:1.6.0_45-fcs.x86_64`.

I'm not sure of where you got the file that you are referring to from but when looking at Java's site, the file isn't actually `jdk-6u45-linux-amd64.rpm` but `jdk-6u45-linux-amd64.rpm.bin` and it isn't installed with `rpm`.

Comment: Tried that, same result: `package jdk-6u45-linux-amd64 is not installed`

Comment: @user435421 Add the output of `rpm -qa | grep ^jdk` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`rpm -i` accepts as a parameter a **file name**.

`rpm -q` accetps as a parameter a **package name**.

Note that filename does not enforce package name and vice versa.

You can:

```
mv jdk-6u45-linux-amd64.rpm some-fancy-name.rpm
rpm -i some-fancy-name.rpm
```

and you will still get the same error. Because the file name does not change the package data inside of the file. Namely the package name.

You can query the package name using `-qp`:

```
rpm -qp jdk-6u45-linux-amd64.rpm
```

Or you can add `-i` to get a bit more information.

In your case the output will likely be `jdk-2000`.

You can query it using:

```
rpm -ql jdk-2000
```